# How to make CSS Grid row height flexible

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I am creating a CSS Grid layout, and I'm unable to get the "auto" value to work for the sizing of row height.

The items keep a minimum height of 1fr, even if their content is small enough to allow them to shrink.
I wrote some text in my children div but I get a lot of space between rows and columns..

I want to create a 3 parent div : A B C, every parent have a grid system as a child, and when I get A1 from server I must put it into A column, B1 into B and so on, but when I get more than 3 children in same column I should create another column inside parent, I'm trying with css grid but I don't know how to achive this mechanism.
this is what I've tried :

```css
 .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    background: #faf;
    border-radius: 5px;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    width: fit-content;
  }

  .item {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #3db5da;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 90px;
    height: fit-content;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
    <p>Hi, I'm a test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

fot he moment the result is this :
[image]

And I want to remove space between items, whatever content is.

I'm trying with display: flex, but for the moment it not work as expected

Expected output :
[image]

**EDIT:** In case if I have  4 items and want to display it in two columns, I have to control the position of the items, I don't want to put 2 items per column if in the first column I already have a place to have 3 items instead of 2, this is a image of how  It displayed when I get 4 items and 2 columns, the output should look like 3 elements in first columns (because there is a place for 3 elements), and the last element in the second column.

[image]

[Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-feather-j6yqtt?file=/index.html) :

Comment: Please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50570356/20447387

Comment: I've see it before, but any idea how to achieve the same thing..

Comment: Is this more like a multi-column layout than a grid? e.g. use column-count?

Comment: @AHaworth have you any demo example please ?

Comment: I have posted an answer based on column count.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand now what is needed. Especially the 'destroy' second column. Could you include some images which show various scenarios? I'll probably delete my answer shortly if it doesn't answer the question now

Comment: Sorry for my english, I edited my post with demo link also :)

Comment: You images just don’t match the new written explanation. You have room for 4 elements in the first column but only show 3.

Comment: The images is what I have for now, not the excpectation output

Comment: The one with 3 in the first column is headed Expected output.

Comment: For this one I should have more than 3 in the first column, because there is more space and I must fill it before switch to the next column :/

Comment: If you have any ideas please don't hesitate to reply, I'm still looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Can you use display:block with column-count? Looks like it's well supported

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a flexbox example to fill the first column before the second, but flexbox doesn't support an easy way to map a gap between columns.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something odd has happened here. Initially the HTML 'knew' where the column split was to come - and that still seems to be the case in the fiddle, but in the CSS within the post column-count is now used, but the first sentence talks about flex. Which are you advocating?

Comment: @AHaworth in the first one I posted I realized I hard coded 2 columns, but that might not be what you wanted, so I updated post and JSFiddle. I'll update

Comment: Hi, mine was just a comment, I'm not the question owner.

Comment: Hin I edited my question, can you take a look please ?

Comment: @alainber82 For column-count, each browser may have it's own balancing algorithm, and the goal is to equalize the height of the columns, so it's not terribly configurable.

Comment: Don't understand, when I add background to my parent div I get only first column colored (with your second answer).. please take a look : https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-firefly-xv3333?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning English, so if I make any mistakes, I apologize.
From what I understood, the issue is that the item's height is not decreasing correctly, right? This happens because you set the value of height as fit-content and a very large padding of 15px. I changed the padding to 5px and instead of height: fit-content, I used min-height: fit-content.

```
.item {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #3db5da;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 90px;
  min-height: fit-content;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rDCb.png)

Was this what you were looking for, or did I get lost?

Comment: No it's not what I'm looking for, I update my questions with the expected result.